# Mistake or typo likely to be in the definition of the covariance matrix of two random variables

Tags: covariance, kalman-filter

I read the slides in [this link](https://ecse.monash.edu/centres/irrc/LKPubs/Kalman.pdf) : **Understanding and Applying Kalman Filtering, Lindsay Kleeman**

On slide 6, there is IMHO a mistake in the definition of covariance matrix of two random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$

I think it shoud be $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, (x_1 - \overline{x_1})(x_2 - \overline{x_2}). p(x_1,x_2)\mathrm dx_1 \,\mathrm dx_2$$ with p the joint PDF of $x_1$ and $x_2$

instead of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, (x_1 - \overline{x_1})(x_2 - \overline{x_2}). p(x_1,x_1)\mathrm dx_1 \,\mathrm dx_2$$ as on slide 6.

Am I right?

Comment: Yep.... of course.........

Comment: Thanks for the double check.